# Inheritance from macros in Qt4

Tags: c++, macros, qt4

Part of my code looks something like this.

```
#include <QObject>
#define MYMACRO : public QObject
#define SIGNAL_MACRO Q_OBJECT signals: void testSignal(std::string s);
#define EMIT_MACRO emit testsignal(s);

class myclass MYMACRO
{
   SIGNAL_MACRO
...

void myclass::method()
{
   std::string s("string");
   EMIT_MACRO
}
```

If I write the contents of the macros to where they should be expanded it works fine. But if I keep the macros and let the preprocessor do the job then I get an 'undefined reference to myclass::testSignal(std::string)'. I don't understand what's the difference. The preprocessor should expand the macros as they are first encountered, exactly as if I'd written them out myself. I thought I could write anything in a macro and it will simply be copy-pasted to where it's needed.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but do you intend to make your code hard to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here might be that the Qt meta-object compiler is run before the C++ pre-processor, so it doesn't get to see the `Q_OBJECT` inside the `SIGNAL_MACRO`. From the [Qt Reference Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/moc.html):

> The moc tool reads a C++ header file. If it finds one or more class
>   declarations that contain the Q_OBJECT macro, it produces a C++ source
>   file containing the meta-object code for those classes.

My advice is, don't do it this way.

Comment: First of all, sorry if this was hard to read. I tried to create a simple example to illustrate my problem.
Secondly, thank you. I didn't think of the fact that qmake runs first.
Thirdly, I understand that this looks extremely ugly but I actually had a valid reason for this. But anyway, I'll try some other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that when you 'write the contents of the macros' manually, that you are writing code that is exactly the same as that produced by expansion of the macros?

It looks to me that the SIGNAL_MACRO *declares* the `testSignal()` function, but does not *define* it, i.e. function has no body, which would certainly result in the error you are seeing.

However, it is hard to tell from your code, because the use of macros is makes things confusing.  I would kindly advise you not to use macros in this way, because it makes the code very hard to read and understand.

Comment: In Qt the body of a signal is not defined, so that wouldn't cause the problem. But it doesn't matter, because TonyK already answered my problem.